# Not able to run Single Test Using Night Watch and Selenium in Chrome Browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm getting "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object" when trying to run a single test case using night watch.

I have 2 test files namely mywrkouthomepage.js and mywrkoutlogin.js under tests directory. I am planning to run mywrkoutlogin.js using the command node nightwatch --test tests\mywrkoutlogin and it throws me with an exception "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object"

Comment: always do this to get prompt reply- provide more info- share code, screenshot or console error, paste here complete error message.

Answer (score -1):

Krishna,

File extension is missing in command you tried to run. Try to append **.js**:

`nightwatch --test tests\mywrkoutlogin.js`

Good luck!